# I want to sort out ranked points (MySQL)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sorting

I have a user, this is in a mysql table with other users. All users have their own points. I want to find out on which place my user is when I arrange all the points.

Working with JavaScript, if it comes with pure MySQL commands would be acceptable.

So I got this Users

Foo 134 Points
   Fubar 32 Points
   Bao 4 Points
   Fuo 231 Points
   Bar 12 Points

Now I need the Rank of Fubar so:

1. Fuo 231 Points
2. Foo 134 Points
3. Fubar 32 Points
4. Bar 12 Points
5. Bao 4 Points

so Fubar had the rank 3

Comment: It is always good to add some `DDL` and example data to question so other's can easily understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Please be careful using tags. I've removed the [tag:table] tag; if you click it and read the description, you'll see why. Thank you.

Comment: More broadly, all you need to do is rank people by `users.points`? Thinking through the problem, what you need to do is return a list of users and their points, sorted by points, and then assign a rank to them based on whether or not the person preceedig them has more points than they do to account for two users having the same number of points (you should assign them the same rank, I presume?). You can do that in JavaScript [by looping over your array of users](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and just checking that condition above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following query

```
set @ranking=0;
select @ranking:=@ranking+1 AS rank,* from table_name order by points desc;
```

Comment: Then you will have to add another order by.. `order by points desc, other_points desc`